# logback.xml (or other resources) not found in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader, slf4j, logback

I'm developing a web application using Logback as logging framework, and am testing it in Tomcat 6. For some reason, **logback.xml** does not get read.

- **logback.xml** is in **WEB-INF/classes**.
- Logback itself is in **WEB-INF/lib**.
- I'm using SLF4J.
- Logback is used: I see log messages in catalina.out, and `LoggerFactory.getLogger(...)` returns logback logger instances.
- I've already reloaded the app and even restarted Tomcat.

Any idea what's going on?

Update: It appears something deeper is going on. These return `null`:

```
// in a servlet
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/logback.xml");
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("MyServlet.class");
```

When I log the classloader, everything appears fine:

```
22:32:11.221 [http-8080-1] INFO test.MyServlet - WebappClassLoader
  context: /test
  delegate: false
  repositories:
     /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@630f41e9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a Linux permission thing. Some directory lacked read/execute permissions. I accidentally fixed it when [I ran into more problems with that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825466/tomcat-6-refuses-a-valid-docbase).