# Tomcat 6 refuses a valid docBase

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat6

This is my webapp context file, **/etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost/ri.xml**

```
<Context docBase="/home/bart/Dropbox/projects/RevoraIndieSite/webapp" reloadable="true">

</Context>
```

However, Tomcat complains:

```
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor ri.xml
28-Apr-2011 23:44:04 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /home/bart/Dropbox/projects/RevoraIndieSite/webapp does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4249)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4418)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1337)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1601)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
28-Apr-2011 23:44:04 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
28-Apr-2011 23:44:04 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
28-Apr-2011 23:44:04 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/ri] startup failed due to previous errors
28-Apr-2011 23:44:04 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext stop
INFO: Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/ri] has not been started
```

But the directory exists, and is readable for everyone.

```
bart@bart-laptop:~$ ls -l /home/bart/Dropbox/projects/RevoraIndieSite
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 3 bart bart 4096 2011-04-20 20:46 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 bart bart 4096 2011-04-27 23:11 bin-tools
-rw-r--r-- 1 bart bart  971 2011-04-27 23:15 build.xml
drwxr-xr-x 4 bart bart 4096 2011-03-30 22:42 export
-rw-r--r-- 1 bart bart  290 2011-03-30 22:36 ivysettings.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 bart bart 1214 2011-04-27 23:08 ivy.xml
drwxr-xr-x 4 bart bart 4096 2011-04-28 23:33 src
drwxr-xr-x 3 bart bart 4096 2011-04-27 22:09 src-tools
drwxr-xr-x 3 bart bart 4096 2011-02-27 17:33 webapp
```

It's a default Tomcat 6 installation from the Ubuntu 10.10 repository, with no other changes.

Comment: What's the `appbase` of your `host` element in `server.xml`? Is it a parent of your `docBase`?

Comment: @matt: The default, `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps`, so no parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webapp directory needs write permisson as well. Furthermore it is a good practice to set owner of this directory as the same that runs tomcat instance (which is tomcat6 user on ubuntu if i am not wrong)
so try
`chown -R tomcat6:tomcat6 webapps`
or give write permisson to webapps forlder for others
`chmod 766 webapps`

Comment: I can try giving write permissions, but why would they be needed? I've run this app in this same configuration before, and it worked.

Comment: I found the problem, it was indeed something with permissions, but not write. Turned out `Dropbox` needed a `+rx`. Strange, I thought `webapp` having `r` & `x` should have been enough.

Comment: Well, I have the perfect solution now. Instead of editing the app under my own user and testing it on the system-wide Tomcat service, I'm now deploying it to a manually started Tomcat instance running under my user. Makes editing the configuration files and such easier too.

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom: it needs write access to 'webapps' so that it can deploy/undeploy web-apps.

Comment: @EJP: I guess it depends on the app, but those I've made run fine with read access only. Tomcat doesn't need to write anything inside the webapp's directory. Logs, temp, etc. are all somewhere outside of it.

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom: I repeat. Tomcat needs to write *web-apps* inside the webapps directory, when hot deploying/undeploying. Presumbly your other deployments aren't using hot-deploy.

Comment: Ah, yes, it would need that if I used hot deploy, but I'm talking about the directory `webapp` (no "s"), which contains just my application, i.e. `WEB-INF` and static files. The docBase. I'm not using the `webapps` directory (appBase) at all, but I left it at the default.

Answer (score 0):

You may well have a ri.xml file & ri directory in the `conf/Catalina/[host]`directory, left over from a previous deployment attempt. Check for that and delete it.